# macOS swift: connecting to German "internetmarke" via SOAP

Tags: swift, macos, soap

Here is my solution for connecting to the German online stamp serivce "Internetmarke" via SOAP for those who need to do the same (sometimes)

```swift
    private func stampLogIn() {
        let aktDate = dateFormatterSOAP.string(from: Date())
        
        let partnerID: String = "XXXXX"
        let partnerKey: String = "sajklfgweiqulskdjfvbluw"
        
        let sign: String = partnerID + "::" + aktDate + "::1::" + partnerKey
        
        let signature_key = Insecure.MD5.hash(data: sign.data(using: .utf8)!).map {String(format: "%02x", $0)}.joined()

        let message: String = """
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v3="http://oneclickforapp.dpag.de/V3">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <v3:PARTNER_ID>\(partnerID)</v3:PARTNER_ID>
  <v3:REQUEST_TIMESTAMP>\(aktDate)</v3:REQUEST_TIMESTAMP>
  <v3:KEY_PHASE>1</v3:KEY_PHASE>
  <v3:PARTNER_SIGNATURE>\(signature_key.prefix(8))</v3:PARTNER_SIGNATURE>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <v3:AuthenticateUserRequest>
   <v3:username>login_mail@dhldp-test.de</v3:username>
   <v3:password>myPassword</v3:password>
  </v3:AuthenticateUserRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""
        let urlString = "https://internetmarke.deutschepost.de/OneClickForAppV3?wsdl"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("\(message.count)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.httpBody = message.data(using: .utf8)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared
            .dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,
                      completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                guard error == nil else {
                    // Handle the error
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }
                // Continue checking response or data...
                let dataStr = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                // Here goes XML-Parsing
                print(dataStr)
            })
        task.resume()
    }
```

This ist only for the first step. Of course the other steps have to be done analogically. To be done: the XML parsing of the response.